# Calculating (dis)similarity between different types of features

Tags: clustering, distance-functions

Disclaimer: I understand that this question is specific to the types of data, the end goal, etc. but I just wanted to get some quick tips regarding calculating dissimilarity between different types of data. This/clustering is probably the area of ML in which I am least comfortable.

Let's say I have a dataset with 3 features: Age (integer), location(lat, long) and #posts (integer). What's one simple way I can calculate the 'distance' between two members of this dataset besides the most naive implementation of Euclidean distance (all I can meaningfully think of at the moment)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, multidimensional scaling (MDS) would serve your purposes I believe: [Wikipedia: MDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm looking more for a suggestion on how I would calculate this 'dissimilarity' to use in MDS with different types of features, e.g. count data, lat/long, age.

Comment: All three your features are scale (quantitative numeric) type. You may select among many distances, Euclidean being one.

Comment: @Dalmo MDS needs a dissimilarity; he is asking how to compute a reasonable similarity on such data. Afterwards, he can use MDS to project the data to Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty good question.

The problem is; I have not yet seen a convincing good answer.

A computer probably won't be able to figure out how to best combine *age* and *geographic distance* into a sensible similarity measure; anything will be heuristic.

The standard technique would be to use z-standardization to give each feature the same weight; but as latitude and longitude are two features, you may also want to assign them less weight.
Then compute Euclidean distance on the standardized data.

But you may need to perform much more preprocessing. For example, $\#posts$ may be highly skewed; and then it may be beneficial to analyze $\log(\#posts + 1)$ instead.

You may need to perform **active metric learning**, and use user feedback to figure out appropriate weights for your distance function. Don't just blindly use Euclidean distance, it will put too much weight on one feature or another.